# Select tabs using right click in Kendo Tabstrip

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to select tabs in Kendo Tabstrip (see demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index)) using right click in addition to left click. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will work,

```
$('#tabstrip [role="tab"]').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
   $('#tabstrip').getKendoTabStrip().select($(this));
   return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks, however this doesn't have the same effect as click as the other tab keeps selected. I tried with `$('#tabstrip').getKendoTabStrip().deactivateTab(position);` but I don't know how to populate `position`

Comment: @pgschr, I tested this script with firefox, it is working fine as expected. In which browser this happening(other tab keeps selected)?

Comment: I tested on chrome, I create the tabs dynamically, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @pgschr, May be, If previous selected tab color is the only problem then use the below script
$('#tabstrip [role="tab"]').removeClass('k-state-active');
//Full Script is
$('#tabstrip [role="tab"]').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
   $('#tabstrip [role="tab"]').removeClass('k-state-active');
   $('#tabstrip').getKendoTabStrip().select($(this));
   return false;
});